# RavenDB: How do I find/use custom Analyzers when in Embedded/RunInMemory mode?

Tags: ravendb

I would like to make use of [this Alphanumeric Analyzer](http://www.tomdupont.net/2013/05/alphanumeric-lucene-analyzer-for-ravendb.html) in my RavenDB implementation. I have it working in my staging environment (actual RavenDB server installation), but I am having trouble when it comes to unit tests run in my development environment (VS2013). I have indexes I create during my unit tests, and their creation fails when RavenDB is unable to find the custom analyzer.

I understand that for an installed RavenDB server, you drop the compiled DLL in \Analyzers\ and restart the server for the analyzer to be recognized. However, how do I achieve this when the RavenDB DocumentStore is running in memory from an EmbeddableDocumentStore? I've tried creating an \Analyzers\ directory with the DLL in it in several places in my project's \bin\Debug\ but that didn't seem to do anything.

I have spent several hours going through the RavenDB documentation and assorted Google results to no avail. If the answer's published somewhere, it appears to be extremely buried and difficult to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a reference to the analyzer assembly from your test project.  It doesn't matter what directory it's in.  Assuming the analyzer is used by your index with the full qualified name of the assembly, it should pick it up.

Comment: It seems so simple now, but I never would have thought of that. Thank you!

Comment: We added a step to our build script to copy the analyzer dlls across. This works well when you don't want to add additional dependencies to your solutions.

Comment: If you're working with an older version of `Raven.Database` this might not work for you. I had to updated to latest (3.5) before I got this to work.