# RavenDb - How to use Custom Analyzer (NGram)

Tags: ravendb, lucene.net, lexical-analysis, n-gram

i'm learning ravenDb, and i'm trying to use it's full power with lucene's custom analyzers.

according to the [docs](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/indexes/using-analyzers) -

> The analyzer you are referencing to has to be available to the RavenDB server instance. When using analyzers that do not come with the default Lucene.NET distribution, you need to drop all the necessary DLLs into the "Analyzers" folder of the RavenDB server directory, and use their fully qualified type name (including the assembly name).

seems pretty simple, even too simple but i tried with no luck.
i used this code (CustomAnalyzers project) to implement NGramAnalyzer (and filter) in CustomAnalyzer :

[This specific implementation isn't SO important, for now i'm trying to use any custom analyzer, and proceed. I included it anyway if it will help.]

```
    public class NGramTokenFilter : TokenFilter
{
    public static int DEFAULT_MIN_NGRAM_SIZE = 1;
    public static int DEFAULT_MAX_NGRAM_SIZE = 2;
    private int minGram, maxGram;
    private char[] curTermBuffer;
    private int curTermLength;
    private int curGramSize;
    private int curPos;
    private int tokStart;
    private TermAttribute termAtt;
    private OffsetAttribute offsetAtt;
    public NGramTokenFilter(TokenStream input, int minGram, int maxGram)
        : base(input)
    {

        if (minGram < 1)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("minGram must be greater than zero");
        }
        if (minGram > maxGram)
        {
            throw new System.ArgumentException("minGram must not be greater than maxGram");
        }
        this.minGram = minGram;
        this.maxGram = maxGram;

        this.termAtt = AddAttribute<TermAttribute>();
        this.offsetAtt = AddAttribute<OffsetAttribute>();
    }

    public NGramTokenFilter(TokenStream input)
        : this(input, DEFAULT_MIN_NGRAM_SIZE, DEFAULT_MAX_NGRAM_SIZE)
    {
    }

    public override bool IncrementToken()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (curTermBuffer == null)
            {
                if (!input.IncrementToken())
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    curTermBuffer = (char[])termAtt.TermBuffer().Clone();
                    curTermLength = termAtt.TermLength();
                    curGramSize = minGram;
                    curPos = 0;
                    tokStart = offsetAtt.StartOffset;
                }
            }
            while (curGramSize <= maxGram)
            {
                while (curPos + curGramSize <= curTermLength)
                {     // while there is input
                    ClearAttributes();
                    termAtt.SetTermBuffer(curTermBuffer, curPos, curGramSize);
                    offsetAtt.SetOffset(tokStart + curPos, tokStart + curPos + curGramSize);
                    curPos++;
                    return true;
                }
                curGramSize++;                         // increase n-gram size
                curPos = 0;
            }
            curTermBuffer = null;
        }
    }
    public override void Reset()
    {
        base.Reset();
        curTermBuffer = null;
    }
}
public class NGramAnalyzer : Analyzer
{
    public override TokenStream TokenStream(string fieldName, TextReader reader)
    {
        var tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_29, reader) { MaxTokenLength = 255 };
        TokenStream filter = new StandardFilter(tokenizer);
        filter = new LowerCaseFilter(filter);
        filter = new StopFilter(false, filter, StandardAnalyzer.STOP_WORDS_SET);
        return new NGramTokenFilter(filter, 2, 6);
    }
}
```

And added the dlls(all the dlls from the class library) to the Analyzers directory (the Analyzers wasn't there so i added new folder, couldn't find any other analyzers folder...)

[image]

[image]

in another project (which is referencing the 'CustomAnalyzers' Project) i'm trying to build an index :

```
public class NGramIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Book>
{
    public NGramIndex()
    {
        Map = books => from book in books
                        select new
                        {
                            book.Body
                        };

        Indexes.Add(x => x.Body, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Analyzers.Add(x => x.Body, typeof(NGramAnalyzer).FullName);
    }
}
```

when i run this code

```
var store = new DocumentStore { Url = "MY_URL", DefaultDatabase = "MY_DB" }.Initialize();
        new NGramIndex().Execute(store);
```

i get this exception -

> 'Raven.Abstractions.Exceptions.IndexCompilationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Cannot find analyzer type 'CustomAnalyzers.NGramAnalyzer, CustomAnalyzers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' for field: Body

i tried also using 'AssemblyQualifiedName' or hard code the full name.
i looked in these stackoverflow questinos :
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44564094/custom-analyzer-for-ravendb)
[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502900/ravendb-how-do-i-find-use-custom-analyzers-when-in-embedded-runinmemory-mode)
and couldn't find an answer.

and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/n1hYPOKAJxs) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ravendb/dyEidpm-LYE)
and tried to restart the ravendb.

please show how you used custom analyzer in ravendb.
thx.

Comment: I assume that `CustomAnalyzer.dll` is in the analyzer folder, that it was compiled against the same Lucene dll that is deployed on the server, right?

Comment: You can enable the fusion log to see why it can't find it.

Comment: CustomAnalyzer.dll is the dll of class library which has NGram class in it and referencing lucene dll from Nuget. and I deployed the same lucene dll to the server. all the bin/debug folder is in the analyzers folder

Comment: another note: the project that builds the index is the website project named 'sampleRavenWebsite' which is referencing the class library project 'Custom Analyzers'

Comment: ok ... so after hours of debugging - iwas just a typo in the url.. uhhhhhhhhhh so frustrating.. thank you very much for your help

Comment: btw (if it would help anyone) i had another exception - "AddAttribute() only accepts an interface that extends Attribute, but Lucene.Net.Analysis.Tokenattributes.TermAttribute does not fulfil this contract." - needed to change to ITermAttribute both in decleration and in AddAttribute<Type>

Comment: You cannot use the Lucene from nuget, you _have_ to use the lucene dll from the ravendb server, they are not the same